# How to apply an array of classes to classList.contains?

Tags: javascript

In my HTML, I have a `div` like so:

```
<div class="a b c"></div>
```

In my JavaScript, I have an array of classes that I'm interested in:

```
var goodClasses = ['a', 'c'];
```

In good browsers, I can use the awesome [`classList`](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/01/classlist-in-firefox-3-6/) feature to test whether or not my `div` has the appropriate classes:

```
return div.classList.contains(goodClasses[0], goodClasses[1]);
```

This is okay, but what I'd really like to do is something like this (the syntax is silly, but this is the general idea):

```
return div.classList.contains.apply(div, goodClasses);
```

Is there some way to do this? If I have to loop through my array of classes anyway, `classList` becomes a whole lot less cool.

Comment: It will not work as you might think. `classList.contains` only considers the first parameter anyway. All others are ignored. `div.classList.contains(goodClasses[0], goodClasses[1]);` does **not** work. See: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/VcrnD/1/ . You **have to** iterate.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As [@Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling) correctly points out, `classList.contains` accepts only one argument.

If your supported browsers support the `every()` method on `Array`, you could do this:

```
return goodClasses.every( function( c ) {
    return div.classList.contains( c );
});
```

Browsers that don't support it can use [the MDC compatibility fix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```
if (!Array.prototype.every)
{
  Array.prototype.every = function(fun /*, thisp */)
  {
    "use strict";

    if (this === void 0 || this === null)
      throw new TypeError();

    var t = Object(this);
    var len = t.length >>> 0;
    if (typeof fun !== "function")
      throw new TypeError();

    var thisp = arguments[1];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      if (i in t && !fun.call(thisp, t[i], i, t))
        return false;
    }

    return true;
  };
}
```

Comment: [Looks like](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every#browser_compatibility) every browser supports `every` nowadays.

Answer (score -1):

This should work

```
String(el.className).includes(class)
```

Comment: This does not work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).