# How exactly does element.classList.contains() work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I needed to use `element.classList.contains('some-class')` to check if an element contains at least one of three classes, so I wrote:

```
if (element.classList.contains('class1', 'class2', 'class3')) {
  // do stuff here
}
```

The result was - if the element has 'class1', it returns true, no matter if it has 'class2' or/and 'class3', and 
    `// do stuff here`
executes. However, if it has 'class2' and/or 'class3', it returns false and
    `// do stuff here`
does not execute.

I worked around it with:

```
if (element.classList.contains('class1') || element.classList.contains('class2') || element.classList.contains('class3')) {
  // do stuff here 
}
```

Comment: contains - Checks if an element's list of classes contains a specific class. https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-domtokenlist So yes, you will need to check if an element contains A or contains B or contains C

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This function only takes one parameter. The contains method is used to check if your classList contains a singular element. The code block that you have posted at the bottom is a good workaround. But unfortunately what you are trying to do at the top is beyond the reach of the classList API.

Comment: This is correct. You can find more elegant "workaround" here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391448/how-to-apply-an-array-of-classes-to-classlist-contains

Comment: is this still the case?

Answer (score 3):

It tells you if the class name you pass as the first argument is one of the classes the element is a member of.

As with all JavaScript functions, you can pass as many additional arguments are you like. The `contains` function just doesn't do anything with them.

Answer (score 1):

```
var c = element.classList;
var any = c.contains( 'class1' ) || c.contains( 'class2' ) || c.contains( 'class3' );
var all = c.contains( 'class1' ) && c.contains( 'class2' ) && c.contains( 'class3' );
```

Answer (score 0):

try `document.querySelectorAll`

HTML:

```
<div class="class1"></div>
<!--<div class="class2"></div> -->
<!-- <div class="class3"></div> -->

<div id="result"></div>
```

Javascript

```
var el = document.querySelectorAll('.class1, .class2, .class3');
var result = document.getElementById('result');

result.innerHTML = el.length;
```

demo: https://codepen.io/fatihhayri/pen/weqzWE

Answer (score 0):

It works for me like this:

```js
let elem = document.querySelector("span");

if (elem.classList.contains('beta')) {
elem.textContent = "The classList contains 'beta'";
} else {
elem.textContent = "The classList does not contain 'beta'";
}
```

```html
<span class="alpha beta gamma"></span>
```